# Terminating Java Application

Tags: java, suse

I have a Java application on a suseEnvironment which I start with a SH file.

I use the command: startFile.sh &.

If I logged in via putty, the application is still running after I've closed putty.

If I'm logged in at suse directly (via UI) and I start the application, It will be terminated after I've logged out from SUSE.

What is the difference?

Comment: Do you log out of the remote system before closing putty, or do you close putty without logging out?

Answer (score 0):

Giving `&` only puts it in the background. You also have to do `nohup`:

```
nohup startFile.sh &
```

so that the program doesn't receive SIGHUP.

Comment: Yes I Know, but why is the Application still alive if I start it without nohup via putty after closing putty?

Comment: Because PuTTY probably doesn't simulate a `SIGHUP` when it exits.

Comment: @Juergen Sorry I misread the emphasis in your question. I haven't used Putty for a while, but closing a window, doesn't necessarily mean the underlying connection is broken. If you use password login, does Putty ask you for a password on reconnect?

Comment: @Anthon Yes Putty asks for the PW.

Comment: @Juergen Do you have `disown -h` in your `~/.bash_logout` (or `/bash/bash.bash_logout`?